# Why are both of these valid solutions?

Tags: java

I had a homework problem that was as follows:

> A 2-dimensional 3x3 array of ints, has been created and assigned to tictactoe. Write an expression whose value is true if the elements of the first row are all equal.

My solution was:

```
tictactoe[0][1] == tictactoe[0][0] && tictactoe[0][0] == tictactoe[0][2]
```

While my friends was:

```
tictactoe[0][1] == tictactoe[0][1] && tictactoe[0][0] == tictactoe[0][2]
```

I was just wondering why both of these solutions are correct as it seems like his is redundant and should be wrong.

Comment: Is there a misprint in the second solution? It compares `tictactoe[0][1]` to istelf.

Comment: @Ivan I think that is what is causing the friend's solution to be correct.

Comment: What makes you think your friends solution is correct? (it's not)

Comment: Did you do a negative test? Have you verified that when values are different, the result is `false`.

Comment: Teachers are people too  ... so  they make mistakes

Comment: @Plirkee This was a question for My Programming Lab which runs the code and makes sure that it gives the desired output. It accepted both of the given answers, so it likely wasn't a mistake.

Comment: @Oleg This was a question for My Programming Lab which runs the code and makes sure that it gives the desired output. It accepted both of the given answers, so it likely wasn't a mistake.

Comment: Probably as mentioned by @PM77-1 the testing code doesn't do a negative test and will also pass with `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Oleg said, your friend's solution is not right and will fail when the first row is something like

```
3 4 3
```

As it checks to see if [0][1] == [0][1] , which will always be true, and then if [0][0] == [0][2], which in this case is true, but will give the wrong answer.

In short, your friend's code will fail when the first and last indexes are the same but are different than the second index.